# Where can I find the declaration of mscorlib::_AppDomain, mscorlib::_Type etc

Tags: c++, winapi, clr, clr-hosting

I am using this for my base https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0/sourcecode?fileId=21953&pathId=1366553273

But in my VS2010 I cant get intellisense or go to declaration. I tried google, but it takes me to the .NET documentation.

For example I cant get arguments for (or find where its declared): spDefaultAppDomain->**Load_2**(bstrAssemblyName, &spAssembly);

_AppDomainPtr spDefaultAppDomain = NULL;
_AppDomainPtr is basicly mscorlib::_AppDomain..

Sorry, since I don't have much experience in this type of coding I don't know how to properly formulate the question.

Comment: This is part of CLR [Hosting (Unmanaged API)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385.aspx). You'll need to understand the [Component Object Model (COM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680573.aspx). There are no shortcuts.

Comment: I wish people could tell me in comments why they downvote, there's no lack of "Where can I find" questions on so I don't get it nor can I improve because nobody write anything in the comments about it.

Comment: Good questions on stackoverflow address common programming problems. Not knowing COM and trying to use it doesn't lead to good questions. This question is a good example. You are asking about very basic information, that is readily available (see [COM, DCOM, and Type Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757.aspx), for example).

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236146/Protecting-NET-plus-Application-By-Cplusplus-Unman).

This is how this example declares it:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")
#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only\
            high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")\
            rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")
using namespace mscorlib;
```

I have tested this in VS2017, for this compiler be sure to set Conformance mode to No in C/C++/Language setting for it to compile properly.

Comment: Got error `cannot open source file mscorlib.tlh` after change Conformance mode to No. Otherwise `enum type is nonstandard` in mscorlib.tlh

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLEView.exe and scroll down to Type Libraries in the navigation pane, find the proper type library, right click and click View, there are the declarations.